# the menu is not displayed in the xml file already tried everything, nothing works

Tags: java, android, kotlin, button, navigation

The main problem is that the menu bar is not displayed in my layout file.
I've done a few searches but haven't been able to find a solution or a reason as to why it is behaving this way.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
**my menu file**

```
`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/air"
            android:title="Авиабилеты"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/air"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/bed"
            android:title="Отели"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/bed"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:title="Профиль"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/person"/>
    
    </menu>`
```

> XML
> **my layout file**

```
    `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.gototrip.view.MainSearchTicketFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_700"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Поиск дешевых
                          авиабилетов"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fromEditText"
            android:layout_width="336dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rouded_edittext"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Откуда"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:guidelineUseRtl="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="42dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/whereEditText"
            android:layout_width="336dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rouded_edittext_two"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Куда"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Дата"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPassenger"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Класс"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonFilter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Фильтр"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Where am I doing wrong? I checked some tutorials, and that exactly the process of setting bottom navigation view
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6QRe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not use the rules of material design, you should not have a theme that inherits from material design.
Find the theme.xml according to the Android version of your studio and change the parent to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

[image]